# BPM Service Task Definition - Output Parameter

Tags: jbpm, business-process-management, bpmn

I’m currently creating some Service Tasks for/in jBPM 5.4.

I’m able to define the task so far in the MyServiceTask.conf

```
import org.drools.process.core.datatype.impl.type.StringDataType;
[
   [
     "name" : „MyServiceTask“,
     "parameters" : [
        „parameter1" : new StringDataType()
      ],
    "displayName" : „MyServiceTask",
    "icon" : "icons/myServiceTask.gif"
  ]
]
```

So when I drag this task in my bmpn editor I see something like this

```
input parameters
from: (nothing set) to parameter1
```

How do I define output parameters?

Is it possible to set default mapping values, so that for example per default the process variable „de.xxx.xx.process1/variable1“ will be mapped to „parameter1“?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a results node in your wid:

`import org.drools.process.core.datatype.impl.type.StringDataType;
[
   [
     "name" : "MyServiceTask“,
     "parameters" : [
        "parameter1" : new StringDataType()
      ],
     "results":[
        "result": new StringDataType()
      ],
    "displayName" : „MyServiceTask",
    "icon" : "icons/myServiceTask.gif"
  ]
]`

As far as I know, there is now way to specify mapping.  This has to be done in the bpmn editor.